# Executing 2 async functions sequentially with dependent outputs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, async-await, async.js

I have a module of functions:

```
module.exports = {
         p3: async function(mongo_db,data, cb){
            mongo_db.collection('release', async function(err,coll){
                for(var i = 0; i <= data.searches.length-1; i++) {
                    var rlsId = data.searches[i].releaseId;
                    //console.log("RELEASE ID " + rlsId);
                    var tdcId = data.searches[i].tdcId;
                    if(rlsId !== null || rlsId !== undefined){
                        result = await  coll.findOne({"_id":ObjectId(rlsId)});
                        if(result){
                            //console.log("this is data searches for index " + i+ " " + JSON.stringify(data.searches[i]) 
                            //      + " and data.searches " + JSON.stringify(data.searches) + " and this is result " + JSON.stringify(result));
                            data.searches[i].releaseId = "release::" + result.initiativeId + "::" + result.name;
                            data.searches[i].tdcId = "testdachar::" +  tdcId;
                            var reservLst = data.searches[i].reservationIds;

                        }
                    }
                }
                if(err){
                    return cb(err)
                }
                return cb(null,data)
                //data_cb(data);
                //cb()
            })
            //return data
        },      p8: async function(mongo_db, data, cb){
            mongo_db.collection('reservation',async function(err,coll){
                for (var i =0 ; i< data.searches.length; i++){

                    if(data.searches[i].reservationIds){
                        var reservLst = data.searches[i].reservationIds;
                        for (var j=0; j<reservLst.length; j++){
                            var reservDoc = await  coll.findOne({"_id":ObjectId(reservLst[j])});
                            if(reservDoc){
                                data.searches[i].reservationIds[j] = "cardreserve::" + reservDoc.accountId; 
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(err){
                    return cb(err);
                }
                return cb(null,data);
                //data_cb(data)
            })
        },

}
```

I am trying to execute p3 and p8 sequentially as the data output of one is passed onto the other. I am trying to use async.waterfall for this, but am having some difficulty coming up with the correct syntax. Can you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Since the chances to get to the callback hell are quite low, it could be as simple as

```
p3(db, data, function(err, result){

    // do something with error or result


    p8(db, data, function(err, result){

        // do something with error or result

    });

});
```